# How to append text to a file without erasing its previous content

Tags: delphi

How do I make Delphi write to a text file without erasing the file's previous contents?
I already know how to add text but as soon as I try adding more it just replaces the previous text that was already in the file.

I have already tried changing the `Rewrite` command to `Write`.

```
procedure TForm1.BtnokClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
    myfile :textfile;
    naam, van, adress : string;
begin 
     adress := edtadress.Text;
     van:= edtvan.Text;
     naam := edtnaam.Text; 
     AssignFile(myfile,'C:\test.txt');
     write(myfile);
     Writeln(myfile,naam);
     writeln(myfile,van);
     writeln(myfile,adress);
     closefile(myfile);
end;
```

Comment: You'd need to use `Append` instead of `Rewrite`.

Comment: Do you have any code? Are we able to see it?

Comment: procedure TForm1.BtnokClick(Sender: TObject);
var
myfile :textfile;
naam, van, adress : string;

begin
adress := edtadress.Text;
van:= edtvan.Text;
naam := edtnaam.Text;
AssignFile(myfile,'C:\test.txt');

write(myfile);
Writeln(myfile,naam);
writeln(myfile,van);
writeln(myfile,adress);

closefile(myfile);

Comment: I am new to this so i am not really sure how to post coding.

Comment: You post it in the question rather than a comment

Answer (score 15):

```
Uses IOUtils;

...

TFile.AppendAllText(filename, sometext);
```

Unless you're working with a really ancient Delphi version.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText

It also lets you specify an encoding as a parameter

Comment: If the poster has included code indicating that the old style IO (AssignFile, etc.) is being used already, clearly IOUtils and TFile is not the relevant solution. :-)

Comment: @kenwhite: That code was not there in the original question... And it's not too late to modernize. :)

Comment: Your answer was added 17 minutes ago, and the code was added 2 hours ago. :-) The problem is that the poster is clearly not familiar with Delphi, so they could try to simply add your code to their existing code, which clearly won't work. It's great to encourage modernization, but you have to a) address the existing question first, and b) explain why they should change and clearly show how to do so.

Answer (score 12):

Call [`Append`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Append) to move to the end of the file:

```
AssignFile(myfile, filename);
Append(myfile);
Write(myfile, sometext);
....
```

Please refer to the documentation. In particular this code example: [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/SystemAppend_(Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/SystemAppend_%28Delphi%29)